# How to select elements from a dataset?

Tags: text

I am having difficulties to extract some elements from a dataset. I imported the .csv file in Mathematica using the following line of code:

```
emails = Import[
  "/Users/Desktop/Spam/email.csv", { "Dataset", All}]
```

and it looks like

[image]

Then I tried to select only the texts with spam equals 1 using this line

```
spamEmail = emails[Select[spam = 1 &], "text"]
```

but it is not working. 
What I would like to do is to select from the dataset only the emails/text with spam=1 and count the words using WordCounts and see their frequency using WordCloud.

Could you please give me suggestions on how to select only those elements?
Thanks

Comment: Try `spam == 1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `"HeaderLines" -> 1` to `Import` to have `"text"` and `"spam"` as keys:

```
emails2 = Import["/Users/Desktop/Spam/email.csv", "Dataset", "HeaderLines" -> 1]

spamEmail  = emails2[Select[#spam == 1 &], {"text"}]
```

or

```
spamEmail  = emails2[Select[Slot["spam"] ==1 &], {"text"}]
```

Alternatively, if you use `Import` as you did

```
emails = Import["/Users/Desktop/Spam/email.csv", { "Dataset", All}]
```

then, you can use `Part`s for filtering, i.e.,

```
emails[Select[#[[2]] == 1& ], {#[[1]]&}]
```

Comment: I am getting the following error message: Failure. Message: Part text is not applicable to expressions of the form (String,). Tag: Dataset

Comment: What is the output from `emails // Take[#, 2] & // InputForm`?

Comment: @math.world Here's what I get from a randomly created `Dataset` that looks like it has the same structure as yours: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJlHm.png -- Works like it says it should in the documentation for `Dataset`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 In your screenshot the first row has a light gray background. In the OP's screenshot it is white. So I think the underlying data is a list of lists, not a list of associations. Which is why I asked for the `InputForm`.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi Thanks. I missed that.  I think you're right.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help